# Normal bundle of exceptional divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the conifold singularity from this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121180/normal-bundle-of-exceptional-locus-of-the-conifold)

It says the normal (or maybe the conormal?) bundle to $P^1$ is the kernel of the map
$$
O^4 \to O(1) \oplus O(1) \oplus O
$$
given by the matrix given by partial derivatives of the equations with respect to $x,y,z,w$ at $x = y = z = w = 0$.

Can anyone explain explicitly how to get this?

------------------------update----------------------

I've quickly browsed Fulton's book Riemann-Roch Algebra.

I guess the basic idea here is:

If $i:X \to Y$ is smooth, then $C_{Y/X} \to i^*\Omega_{X/Y}$ is an isomorphism by lemma 3.8 of Fulton's book. Therefore, the exact sequence of the conormal sheaf can be viewed as the relative cotangent exact sequence. Then the above map is given by the partial derivative because the map between tangent spaces is given by Jacobian matrix and the dual map is the transpose.

Can anyone confirm this and maybe elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $Z \subset Y \subset X$ with all varieties smooth, then there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to N_{Z/Y} \to N_{Z/X} \to N_{Y/X}\vert_Z 
$$
Apply this to $Z = P^1$, $Y$ being the blowup, and $X = A^4 \times P^1$. Then evidently $N_{Z/X} = O^4$, and $N_{Y/X} = O(1) \oplus O(1) \oplus O$, since $Y$ is the zero locus of a regular section of that bundle.